# What does Java do with my "equals" implementations here?

Tags: java, performance, equals, instanceof, microbenchmark

Today, I've stumbled over the following:

Consider two classes NewClass and NewClass1, which have the following "equals"-methods:

NewClass:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return false;
}

public boolean equals(NewClass obj) {
    return value == obj.getValue();
}
```

NewClass1:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(!(obj instanceof NewClass1)) {
        return false;
    }
    return equals((NewClass1) obj);
}

public boolean equals(NewClass1 obj) {
    return value == obj.getValue();
}
```

What I find weird is that the equals in NewClass1 seems to be exponentially slower than the one in NewClass (for 10.000.000 calls 14ms against 3000ms). At first, I thought this was related to the "instanceof" check, but if I replace "return equals((NewClass1) obj);" with "return false;" in NewClass1, suddenly it runs more or less equally fast. I don't really understand what is happening here, because in my opinion, the return statement in equals(Object) should never actually be called. What am I getting wrong here?

The following is my "benchmarking code", in case I made some mistake there:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    NewClass i1 = new NewClass(1);
    NewClass i2 = new NewClass(1);
    NewClass i3 = new NewClass(5);

    NewClass1 j1 = new NewClass1(1);
    NewClass1 j2 = new NewClass1(1);
    NewClass1 j3 = new NewClass1(5);

    Object o1 = new Object();
    Object o2 = new Object();


    assert(i1.equals(i1));
    assert(i1.equals(i2));
    assert(i1.equals(i3) == false);
    assert(i1.equals(o1) == false);

    assert(j1.equals(j1));
    assert(j1.equals(j2));
    assert(j1.equals(j3) == false);
    assert(j1.equals(o1) == false);


    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
        i1.equals(i1);
        i1.equals(i2);
        i1.equals(o1);
        i1.equals(o2);
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Execution time was "+(end-start)+" ms.");



    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
        j1.equals(j1);
        j1.equals(j2);
        j1.equals(o1);
        j1.equals(o2);
    }

    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Execution time was "+(end-start)+" ms.");
}
```

Comment: Maybe the code gets optimized when you replace it with `return false;` so that `instanceof` doesn't get called?

Comment: @thejh: That would actually make a lot of sense... This should've been an answer, its the first useful comment, at least :) I will check that.

Comment: I hope you realise that your first example contains a bug.  The particular implementation of `equals()` to use is chosen at compile time. This means that if the type of the object is not known at compile time e.g. if you have an `Object` that actually references a `NewClass` instance, you'll always return false.  In particular: `n.equals((Object)n)` is false where n is an instance of `NewClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that it is the instanceof test that is consuming the time.  When you change the final return in that method to always return false, the compiler probably eliminates the conditional, since the result will be the same (return false) regardless of its evaluation.  This would also explain why changing the final return has any effect at all, since as you say it should never actually be reached in the code path.

To put it more generally, a code change can impact performance even if it is not on the executed code path, by changing how the compiler optimizes the code.

Comment: Yep, apparently the code got eliminated, and the "instanceof" was really the slow part :) Another Java mystery solved ^^

Answer (score 2):

In the first example `equals(NewClass)` would ordinarily never be called. `equals(Object)` can be inlined by HotSpot (or similar), and the body of your test can be reduced to effectively nothing.

Back of enveloper calculations can be informative. "10.000.000 calls 8ms" is 1,250,000,000 iterations a second. Assuming a 4 GHz processor, that's about three cycles per iteration. A bit fast to be doing anything worthwhile. In fact the code says 1,000,000,000 not 10,000,000.

In fact in the actual code all the loop body could be eliminated. So, it doesn't really matter what you are measuring - it wont be reliable indication of anything useful. There are many other problems with doing microbenchmarks, which you can read in many other places.

Comment: equals(NewClass) has to be called, or else it would always return false, which is not the case (see the asserts in my benchmarking code).

Comment: Also, I got the benchmark time wrong, it wasn't 8ms but aprox 14ms.

Comment: @x3ro Ah, I see you are actually using the overloadings. 14ms vs 8ms doesn't really matter - it's very few cycles (assuming your description has the right number of iterations, the code says a tiny fraction of a cycle per iteration).

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you always return false. This is very fast. In the second example you have a much longer comparison algorithm

Comment: I know that. But if you read my question again, you will notice that what I am actually confused about is that the instanceof call does not seem to make the difference here, but the line after it, which should never be called, because the JVM should decide to call the other equals method, parameterized with NewClass1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first example does nearly nothing.. You can descrease the iteration number to 100000, again you get the same result, 5 or 6 ms. It means that JVM optimizes aggressively that part of your code.